# SQL I would like to select those caracters before a '-'. Ex ES123-224 would give ES123 and RTE2345-34 would give RTE2345

Tags: sql, sql-server

Ex ES123-224 would give ES123 and RTE2345-34 would give RTE2345

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: `SELECT LEFT('RTE2345-34', CHARINDEX('-',' RTE2345-34'))`??

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?  SQL is just a language, but there are many tools which use it.

Comment: SQL Server. I need to use the fieldname  HSAid. SELECT left(HSAid,charindex('-',HSAid)) gives '-' at the end. How do I get rid of it?

Comment: @LasseW - when comments ask for clarifications or refinements, it's usually better to *[edit]* your question to include the information.

Comment: @LasseW  Good grief man, try at least a little bit to understand what it is you are doing.  A cursory google of what `charindex` does will tell you that it returns the character position of the `-` character.  If this is the 10th character it will return `10`, which is being used in the `left` function.  Have a think on why that `-` character is returned and what you could do to the number returned by `charindex` to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Use LEFT function to return the left part of the character string together with CHARINDEX function to find in what position the '-' is at. 
In order to get rid of the '-' you need to substract 1 from the CHARINDEX result.

LEFT ( character_expression , integer_expression )
Where integer_expression is a positive integer that specifies how many characters of the character_expression will be returned.

```
Declare @str varchar(50)

set @str = 'RTE2345-34'

SELECT LEFT(@str, CHARINDEX('-',@str)-1)
```